# JS срабатывает на все теги <li>. Как сделать, чтобы срабатывало по элементу на который кликают?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать так, чтобы `if (event.target.tagName === 'LI')` срабатывал не на все LI, а только на конкретную?
Спасибо!

```js
let post = document.getElementById('post');
let article = document.querySelector('ol');
let send = document.getElementById('header__request')

post.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (send.value.length == 0) {
    alert('Поле пустое');
  } else {
    let elem = document.createElement('li');
    elem.textContent = send.value;
    article.appendChild(elem);
    post.reset();
  };
});

article.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    this.className = (this.className == 'article line' ? 'article' : 'article line');
  }
})
```

```html
<h1 class="header__title">Список задач</h1>
<form id="post">
  <input class="header__request" type="text" name="Задача" id="header__request">
  <button type="submit" class="header__btn" id="header__btn">Добавить</button>
</form>
<h5>Ваши задачи:</h5>
<ol class="article" start="1">
</ol>
```

Comment: event.target.className = (event.target.className == 'article line' ? 'article' : 'article line'); Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/781g6pyz/

Answer (score 1):

```js
let post = document.getElementById('post');
let article = document.querySelector('ol');
let send = document.getElementById('header__request')

post.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (send.value.length == 0) {
    alert('Поле пустое');
  } else {
    let elem = document.createElement('li');
    elem.textContent = send.value;
    article.appendChild(elem);
    post.reset();
  };
});

    article.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
          event.target.className = (event.target.className == 'article line' ? 
          'article' : 'article line');
       }
    })
```

```css
.line{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header__title">Список задач</h1>
<form id="post">
  <input class="header__request" type="text" name="Задача" id="header__request">
  <button type="submit" class="header__btn" id="header__btn">Добавить</button>
</form>
<h5>Ваши задачи:</h5>
<ol class="article" start="1">
</ol>
```